# PostgresSql Query

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to get the activity_id of the 1st "email" activity that happened in between the "completed_order" activity in a different column.
tried this below code but instead of getting the id of the first "email" activity, I am getting the id of
"completed_order" activity.

```
SELECT 
  activity_id,  
  customer ,  
  activity, 
  ts,
  case 
    when 
     activity = 'completed_order' and lead(activity) over (partition by customer order by ts) ='email'
    then        
    activity_id
  end as cndn

from activity_stream 
where customer in (
   select customer where customer = 'Lehmanns Marktstand' 
) 
order by ts
```

[image: Attaching an image, the output of my executed code]

[image: This should be my Desired Result]

Comment: Please add a representation of your desired result

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use something like this, but the description isn't very clear.. add a desired result to your question and drop a comment if it's wrong

```
case 
 when 
  activity = 'email' and lag(activity) over (partition by customer order by ts) ='completed_order'
 then        
  lag(activity_id) over (partition by customer order by ts)
end as cndn
```

This puts the previous lines activity id on the email line if the previous activity was "completed order"

---

Edit, strictly speaking your desired result is given by:

```
case 
 when 
  activity = 'completed_order' and lead(activity) over (partition by customer order by ts) ='email'
 then        
  lead(activity_id) over (partition by customer order by ts)
end as cndn
```

Comment: @Cauis Jard Thanks for replying, I attached a picture of my desired result and your Query worked. thanks a lot

Comment: You're most welcome. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers for info on how to let other users know your question is answered, so it changes appearance on the dashboard

Comment: Your Query gave me the desired result, but the approach is not correct. can you help me in finding the correct approach?

Comment: How can I get the id of the first email after every completed_order activity?

Comment: OK, I will try. So my query is, I want to get the activity_id of the first "email"  activity in a cndn column that happened in between the "completed_order" activity.

Comment: Then is sounds like you want the first answer I gave (the top block of code) and your desired result is not actually your desired result, ie the red numbers are on the wrong lines

Comment: No, The Second Answer is correct and I am getting my desired results but let's suppose after the "completed_order" row there is another row of "viewed_page" activity and then the row of "email" activity. In that case, the above query will fail.

Comment: Hey, If we can move this conversation into a chat, that would be great!